# How to avoid for loop in a Pandas DataFrame for large dataset

Tags: python, pandas

Can you show me a way to optimize this code? It takes dozens of minutes to complete due to large dataset...

```
df['sinistre'] = 0
for index_sin, row_sin in sinistre1.iterrows():
    date_surv = row_sin['DATESURV']
    quit_sin = df.loc[df['id_police'] == row_sin['id_police']]
    for index, row in quit_sin.iterrows():
        if row['DATEEFFE'] < date_surv < row['DATE_FIN']:
            df['sinistre'][index] = 1
```

Here is example dataset for DataFrames `sinistre1` and `df`:

```
>>> sinistre1
  id_police id_sinistre    DATESURV
0      p123        s123  30/05/2017
1      p123        s124  30/11/2017
2      p123        s125  29/02/2018
3      b123        s126  28/02/2018
4      b123        s127  30/05/2018
>>> df
  id_police    DATEEFFE    DATE_FIN  prime  prime2
0      p123  24/01/2017  24/02/2017      0       0
1      p123  24/11/2017  24/12/2017      0      30
2      p123  25/02/2018  25/03/2018     10      10
3      b123  24/02/2018  24/03/2018     20      20
4      b123  24/03/2018  24/04/2018     30       0
```

Here is the expected output *(the idea is when the DATESURV in `sinistre1` is inside the interval `DATEEFFE` & `DATE_FIN` then I flag sinistre)*:

```
  id_police    DATEEFFE    DATE_FIN  prime  prime2  sinistre
0      p123  24/01/2017  24/02/2017      0       0         0
1      p123  24/11/2017  24/12/2017      0      30         1
2      p123  25/02/2018  25/03/2018     10      10         1
3      b123  24/02/2018  24/03/2018     20      20         1
4      b123  24/03/2018  24/04/2018     30       0         0
```

If I can't avoid for loops then please show a better way to loop faster... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Third time you ask a question today, third time I will ask you the same. 1. Describe what you want to do, this is not a code review place. 2nd include expected output

Comment: Loops are slow in pandas/Python. So if you add expected output, we can answer with a vectorized solution which can speed up your code immensely. How did you compare each row in `sinistre1` with each row in `df`? There should be an `id_sinistre` in your `df` as well right? Else you get a `many-to-many` relationship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191796/discussion-between-jezrael-and-sabiri-s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

1. First function [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for convert all datetimes columns
2. Create counter column `sinistre1` for last check membership
3. Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `left` join for data together
4. Filtering by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with `inclusive=True` and get only column `sinistre1` in Series `s`
5. Last overwrite final `sinistre1` by check with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `s`, convert to integer to `True/False` to  `1/0` mapping:

---

```
df['DATEEFFE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATEEFFE'])
df['DATE_FIN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_FIN'])
sinistre1['DATESURV'] = pd.to_datetime(sinistre1['DATESURV'])

df['sinistre1'] = np.arange(len(df))
df1 = df.merge(sinistre1, on='id_police', how='left')
mask = df1['DATESURV'].between(df1['DATEEFFE'], df1['DATE_FIN'], inclusive=False)
s = df1.loc[mask, 'sinistre1']
print (s)
4    1
8    2
9    3
Name: sinistre1, dtype: int32

df['sinistre1'] = df['sinistre1'].isin(s).astype(int)
#alternative
#df['sinistre1'] = np.where(df['sinistre1'].isin(s), 1, 0)
print (df)
  id_police   DATEEFFE   DATE_FIN  prime  prime2  sinistre1
0      p123 2017-01-24 2017-02-24      0       0          0
1      p123 2017-11-24 2017-12-24      0      30          1
2      p123 2018-02-25 2018-03-25     10      10          1
3      b123 2018-02-24 2018-03-24     20      20          1
4      b123 2018-03-24 2018-04-24     30       0          0
```

EDIT:

```
df['DATEEFFE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATEEFFE'])
df['DATE_FIN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_FIN'])
sinistre1['DATESURV'] = pd.to_datetime(sinistre1['DATESURV'])

df1 = df.merge(sinistre1, on='id_police', how='left')
#filter all rows
df2 = df1[df1['DATESURV'].between(df1['DATEEFFE'], df1['DATE_FIN'], inclusive=False)]
print (df2)
  id_police   DATEEFFE   DATE_FIN  prime  prime2 id_sinistre   DATESURV
4      p123 2017-11-24 2017-12-24      0      30        s124 2017-11-30
8      p123 2018-02-25 2018-03-25     10      10        s125 2018-02-28
9      b123 2018-02-24 2018-03-24     20      20        s126 2018-02-28

#left join merge with inditator True
df = df.merge(df2.drop('DATESURV', axis=1), how='left', indicator=True)
#sinistre1 column - first rename and then compare both for 1, esle 0
df = df.rename(columns={'_merge':'sinistre1'})
df['sinistre1'] = df['sinistre1'].eq('both').astype(int)
print (df)
  id_police   DATEEFFE   DATE_FIN  prime  prime2 id_sinistre  sinistre1
0      p123 2017-01-24 2017-02-24      0       0         NaN          0
1      p123 2017-11-24 2017-12-24      0      30        s124          1
2      p123 2018-02-25 2018-03-25     10      10        s125          1
3      b123 2018-02-24 2018-03-24     20      20        s126          1
4      b123 2018-03-24 2018-04-24     30       0         NaN          0
```

Comment: Haven't we already had a conversation about comments like "downvoter, what is wrong with my answer?" Stop leaving these. The next time I delete one of these, it will come with a suspension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jezrael please, can you tell me what should I do to keep sinistre_id in the final df? Thanks again!

Comment: @SabiriS. - Edited answer, also `NaN`s are added if not exist value - first and last.

Answer (score 6):

As I stated in the comments. The accepted answer and merge now dont make sense, because I think OP wants to compare each row in both dataframes and thus needs the key `id_sinistre` in the dataframe `df` as well. Or wants to use `combine_first` like following:

```
df_merge = df.merge(sinistre1, on='id_police', how='left')
df_merge['DATESURV'] = pd.to_datetime(df_merge['DATESURV'])

df_merge['sinistre'] = np.where(df_merge['DATESURV'].between(df_merge['DATEEFFE'], df_merge['DATE_FIN']), 1, 0)

df_merge = df_merge.drop(['DATESURV', 'id_sinistre'], axis=1)

print(df_merge)
    DATEEFFE   DATE_FIN id_police  prime  prime2  sinistre
0 2017-01-24 2017-02-24      p123      0       0         0
1 2017-11-24 2017-12-24      p123      0      30         1
2 2018-02-25 2018-03-25      p123     10      10         1
3 2018-02-24 2018-03-24      b123     20      20         1
4 2018-03-24 2018-04-24      b123     30       0         0
```

Comment: What if `id_police` wasn't the first? what should I put instead of combine_first ... tyy

Comment: That's what im trying to say, you probably have another matching key in your dataframe `df` which matches with  `id_sinistre` in your dataframe `sinistre1`

Comment: No I don't, `id_sinistre` is used to find rows in the original sinistre1 dataframe... in this case only dates and id_police are used

Answer (score 1):

1. Left-merge two datasets on 'id_police' column
2. Write a lambda-function with business logic and apply it to the merged dataset

i.e. (not tested):

```
t_table = pd.merge(sinistre1, df, how='left', on='id_police')
t_table['sinistre'] = [1 if row['DATEEFFE'] < ds< row['DATE_FIN'] else
0 for row,_ in t_table.iterrows()]
```